# Exception: string filename too long (Process)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, phantomjs

I am using the code below to pass an argument to a process

```
 ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 StartInfo.FileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\highcharts\phantomjs.exe");
 StartInfo.Arguments = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\highcharts\highcharts-convert.js");
 StartInfo.Arguments += @" -outfile " + path + @"\chart" + templateData[i].ReportTemplateChartId + ".png -width 800 -infile " + chartoptions1;
 StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
```

In `chartoptions1` I was using a JSON string, but it throws an exception saying *string filename too long*, so I created a text file and tried to pass it, but the chart image is not generated.

Comment: try with `StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` also you can set `StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\highcharts");` and then `StartInfo.FileName ="phantomjs.exe"; `

Comment: by default StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; and we need to set   StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\highcharts");
when we don't have exact path

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN page,

> On Windows Vista and earlier versions of the Windows operating
>   system, the length of the arguments added to the length of the full
>   path to the process must be less than 2080. On Windows 7 and later
>   versions, the length must be less than 32699.

Did you check the length of `StartInfo.Arguments` ?

On the other part, a quick look at this [wiki](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/phantomjs) page on Github,

> -infile: The file to convert, assumes it's either a JSON file, the script checks for the input file to have the extension '.json', or
>   otherwise it assumes it to be an svg file.

So, `-infile` should be a file and not a JSON content. I suppose your `chartoptions1` is quite large, so you have the error message *string filename too long*.

Highcharts may also check the length of the infile path (256 ?)

The running script should have at least read access to the infile and should be resolvable ; especially if you don't specified a working directory, you have to add the full path with infile and not just the filename.

To debug, a working directory issue, simply test with a constant path such as `c:\test`